# C++11: Preventing object being assigned to reference

Tags: c++, c++11, expression-templates

Is there any way to create a type `A` such that:

Given:

`A f(...);`

Then:

Both `auto&& a = f(...);` and `const auto& a = f(...);` give a compile errors?

The reason for this is that in this case, `A` is an expression template which contains references to temporaries (that are provided as arguments to `f`), so I don't want the lifetime of this object extended beyond the current expression.

Note I can prevent `auto a = f(...);` from being an issue just by making `A`s copy constructor private, and making `f(...)` a friend of A if required.

**Example of code** [(ideone link)](http://ideone.com/Jqip4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class AddMathVectors;

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class MathVector
{
public:
  MathVector() {}
  MathVector(const MathVector& x) 
  { 
    std::cout << "Copying" << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
      data[i] = x.data[i];
    }
  }
  T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data[i]; }
  const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return data[i]; }
private:
  std::array<T, N> data;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class AddMathVectors
{
public:
  AddMathVectors(const MathVector<T,N>& v1, const MathVector<T,N>& v2) : v1(v1), v2(v2) {}
  operator MathVector<T,N>()
  {
    MathVector<T, N> result;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    {
      result[i] = v1[i];
      result[i] += v2[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
private:
  const MathVector<T,N>& v1;
  const MathVector<T,N>& v2;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
AddMathVectors<T,N> operator+(const MathVector<T,N>& v1, const MathVector<T,N>& v2)
{
  return AddMathVectors<T,N>(v1, v2);
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
MathVector<T, N> ints()
{
  MathVector<T, N> result;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
  {
    result[i] = i;
  }
  return result;
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
MathVector<T, N> squares()
{
  MathVector<T, N> result;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
  {
    result[i] = i * i;
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  // OK, notice no copies also!
  MathVector<int, 100> x1 = ints<int, 100>() + squares<int, 100>(); 

  // Should be invalid, ref to temp in returned object
  auto&& x2 = ints<int, 100>() + squares<int, 100>(); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. They take them as arguments to `f`.

Comment: Short answer: No. However, [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/libs/proto/) has the same design situation, so you should see how that library works around it (`proto::deep_copy`).

Comment: Just for interest, could you paste some code that shows why you're doing this? (ie. implementation of A and f)

Comment: Ayjay: I've added code to the example.

Answer (score 5):

Given any temporary object, it is always legal in C++ to extend the lifetime of that temporary by binding it to a `const&` or `&&` variable. Ultimately, if you're dealing with lazy evaluation and the like, you have to ask the user not to use `const auto &` or `auto &&`. There's nothing in C++11 that allows you to forcibly prevent the user from doing so.

Comment: Nicol: Out of interest, what does binding temporaries to references offer that return value optimization doesn't? As in, where would `const auto& x = f(...)` or `auto&& x = f(...)` be any faster or otherwise more useful than `auto x = f(...)` (aside from cases where there is no move nor copy constructor defined)?

Comment: @Clinton: If your compiler can elide the copy, then no, it won't be faster. But RVO and NRVO is still relatively new for many C++ programmers, so they tend to use `const&` when they don't need to. And normally, storing a temporary in a `const&` does no actual harm, so until now, there was no real problem.